# handling collision in game android

Tags: android, multithreading, canvas

I am doing a game . The game have:
- A progress bar
- A ball move in screen
- A "blood"
The ball will move in screen .When it collision with "blood" ,the progress bar will create a value and the blood will disappear.
I want the blood hidden in 10s and appear in 5s .I try do it. This my code :

bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ball);

private List bloods = new ArrayList();

public class TimeThread extends Thread{

```
    public void run(){
        while(h < 10000000){
            try {
                sleep(5000);
                h++;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

for(Blood blood : bloods){

```
            if(h%2==0 && h>0)   
            blood.onDraw(canvas);  
            }
            for (int i = bloods.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                Blood blood = bloods.get(i);
                if (blood.isCollition(x2, y2 ,x2 +bitmap.getWidth() , y2 +bitmap.getHeight())) {
                      bloods.remove(blood);
                      progressBar.incrementProgressBy(+40);
                      break;
                }
            }
```

When have collision ,command " bloods.remove(blood);" is implemented .But because "sleep(5000);" should image blood will don't disappear immediately, it will waiting 5s .So ,How do it disappear immediately ?
Please help me .Thanks ,